# Efficient query involving union and virtual/derived table

Tags: mysql, union

Both of these mysql queries produce exactly the same result but query A is a simple union and it has the where postType clause embedded inside individual queries whereas query B has the same where clause applied to the external select of the virtual table which is a union of individual query results. I am concerned that the virtual table from query B might get too large for no good reason if there are a lot of rows but then I am bit confused because how would the order by work for query A ; would it also not have to make a virtual table or something like that for sorting results. All may depend on how order by works for a union ? If order by for a union is also making a temp table; would then query A almost equate to query B in resources(it will be much easier for us to implement query B in our system compared to query A)? Please guide/advise in any way possible.

Query A

```
 SELECT `t1`.*, `t2`.ignorableBalancingColumnFromQuery1
             FROM `t1` INNER JOIN `t2` ON
             `t1`.websiteID= `t2`.ownerID
             AND `t1`.authorID= `t2`.authorID
             AND `t1`.authorID=1559 AND `t1`.postType="simplePost"
 UNION
             SELECT `t1`.*, 111 AS ignorableBalancingColumnFromQuery1
              FROM `t1` where websiteID=1559 AND postType="simplePost" 
 ORDER BY postID limit 0,50
```

Query B

```
 Select * from (
 SELECT `t1`.*,`t2`.ignorableBalancingColumnFromQuery1
             FROM `t1` INNER JOIN `t2` ON
              `t1`.websiteID= `t2`.ownerID
               AND `t1`.authorID= `t2`.authorID
             AND `t1`.authorID=1559
 UNION
             SELECT `t1`.*, 111 AS ignorableBalancingColumnFromQuery1
              FROM `t1` where websiteID=1559
 )
 As sigma  where postType="simplePost" ORDER BY postID limit 0,50
```

EXPLAIN FOR QUERY A

> ```
> id    type                table           type    possible_keys   keys            key_len ref         rows    Extra
> 1     PRIMARY             t2              ref     userID          userID          4       const       1       
> 1     PRIMARY             t1              ref     authorID        authorID        4       const       2       Usingwhere
> 2     UNION               t1              ref     websiteID       websiteID       4       const       9       Usingwhere
> NULL  UNIONRESULT         <union1,2>      ALL     NULL            NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    Usingfilesort
> ```

EXPLAIN FOR QUERY B

> ```
> id    select_type     table       type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref     rows    Extra
> 1     PRIMARY         <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL    10      Using where; Using filesort
> 2     DERIVED         t2          ref     userID          userID          4               1   
> 2     DERIVED         t1          ref     authorID        authorID        4               2       Using where
> 3     UNION           t1          ref     websiteID       websiteID       4               9   
> NULL  UNION RESULT    <union2,3>  ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL
> ```

Comment: Both queries have a cartesian product in the 2nd part of the `UNION`. Why?

Comment: wrote that later to show that the unions will equal number of columns but deleted it from the question realizing it can cause confusion. We are actually doing it by introducing alias columns & yes we need the value from the columns from the first select query involving a join.  The main concern is regarding the impact of the following's use 1) result_from_union_of_two_selects ORDER BY something versus 2) SELECT * FROM (result_from_union_of_two_selects) AS sigma ORDER BY something

Comment: But now the queries won't even run - as you edited them. For your real question, Query A is usually much more efficient than Query B.

Comment: fixed the query now to reflect the equal number of columns between two selects of a union. 
Getting back to the performance issue, wouldn't a union make a temp table somehow to order by data ? & if it does then is it any different from this virtual table select * from (...) as sigma ?